# Can I retrieve funds in a derived address with a high index?

Tags: wallet, address, wallet-recovery, bip32-hd-wallets

I sent funds to a derived address, but I didn't know about the gap limit and how the addresses should be used incrementally. I've used a huge value for the index but wallets only check the first few values -  is there a way I can retrieve them?

Comment: Can you explain a bit on „derived“ address? HD wallet? xpub keys? From which wallet did you send?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use something that lets you generate addresses with a high index. For example, you could use https://iancoleman.io/bip39/ and enter into the `starting from index` box the index you would like to begin deriving addresses at. Then you can get the private keys and import them into your wallet.

IIRC there is not a wallet software that will let you specify where to start deriving addresses.

Comment: @gorod Note the above site does not support Electrum seeds. Answer pebwindkraft's question about wallet software above. If it's electrum mention my name and I'll provide suitable instructions.